# How do I get the checkbox value from a specific cell in a table row using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, tablecell

I have a table that contains multiple checkboxes in each row.  I need to get the value of each individual checkbox.  I've been able to do something like the following to retrieve the value of a checkbox in the first column of a table...

```
$('#myTable tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            //Do something
        }
    });
```

But now I need to iterate over each row, and get the value of each individual checkbox.  This is what I've been trying for a specific checkbox...

```
if($(this).find(':input[type="checkbox"]').eq(0).attr('checked')) {
            myVariable = 'so and so';
        }
        else {
            myVariable = 'something else';
        }
```

Which doesn't work.  Any suggestions on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that clear however going from your second example I assume the 'this' is the tr. The below shows how to get the first checkbox inside the row and test if it is checked

```
if ( $(this).find('input:checkbox:first').is(':checked') ) {...}
```

To iterate all the checkboxes in the row

```
$(this).find('input:checkbox').each( function(){...}
```

To iterate all the checked checkboxes in the row

```
   $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each( function(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove `td:first-child` from your selector?

```
$('#myTable tbody tr  input:checkbox').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Or if you want to group the checkboxes per row somehow:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        //..
    });
});
```